# Flutter: Mutable fields in stateless widgets

Tags: dart, flutter, state, immutability, statelesswidget

The class `StatelessWidget` is marked as `immutable`. However, I am using the `scoped model`, which means that I avoid `StatefulWidget` and use the `model` to alter `state` in `StatelessWidget`. This leads to me having `non-final fields` in `StatelessWidget`, which doesn't cause `errors`, because it's just a `warning`. But I wondered if there is a better way?

Comment: Please add some example code. What you are doing sounds wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stateless widgets should only have final fields, with **no exceptions**. Reason: When the parent widget is rebuilt for some reason (screen rotation, animations, scrolling...), the `build` method of the parent is called, which causes all widgets to be reconstructed.

Classes the extend `StatefulWidget` must follow the same rule, because those are also reconstructed. Only the `State`, which can contain mutable fields, is kept during the lifetime of widget in the layout tree.

There is no reason to avoid `StatefulWidget`. It is a fundamental building block of Flutter.

In fact, `ScopedModelDescendant` is also a stateful widget. The primary benefit of scoped_model is that you can separate the business logic from the widget layer. It doesn't eliminate the need for stateful widgets.

Use stateful widgets for:

- Injecting scoped models into the tree (the widget that builds the `ScopedModel` widget). Store the `Model` instance in the `State`.
- Storing user input (`TextEditingController`, state of a checkbox)
- Animated widgets which require `AnimationController`s
- To store anything that ends with `Controller` (`TabController`, `ScrollController`, ...)

It is often a good idea to make the "page" widgets (widgets which build a `Scaffold`, accessible using the `Navigator`) stateful. Often these are the hosts for scoped models.

Comment: Very helpful! Do you think it would be a mistake to have a ScopedModel wrapped around the root MaterialApp, which acts as a "manager" and has instances of all other models in it to make them accessible from all parts of the app? Would this impact performance negatively?

Comment: It won't affect performance, but it would be cleaner to use a separate `ScopedModel` widget for each model you need (just interlace them, again no performance impact).

Comment: Only create a scoped model if you need the `notifyListeners` feature. In general, if you only need to provide some kind of "global" service, you can use a simple `InheritetWidget` that provides the service (the service would be a simple class)

Comment: I really recommend you to look at the source code of scoped_model to understand what's going on

Comment: I just did that. And I wondered if scoped model is the right approach for me anyways. If you don't mind I would describe the problem I have with architecture really quick:

I like to have very short classes, because it helps me to keep oversight. In practise I would create a widget for each page, then for each ui part of the page and then maybe split each of those again if they have a lot of content.

Comment: The problem: I need communication between them. And to avoid some sort of constructor hell, I tried this scoped model "manager" approach which nests scoped models for each class that I create so that I have access to them from all parts of the app (lazy I know).

Comment: Do you think there is a better approach to accomplish what I want while keeping the "short class structure" that helps me keep oversight and being able to trigger rebuilds of those classes from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here's you question:

> Do you think there is a better approach
> to accomplish what I want while keeping
> the "short class structure" that helps
> me keep oversight and being able to trigger
> rebuilds of those classes from anywhere?

What you're asking for here ↑ seems to be *one more app state management approach* that should be *better than scoped model*.

As you know, **app state management approaches** are a set of techniques that allow you as a developer:

- to **bind data with widgets**.

Binding data with widgets, in turn, helps you as a developer:

- to **rebuild widgets automatically on every change of bound data**.

Maybe, for that purpose, you can make use of **rxdart**:

- [RXDart on Pub.Dev](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)
- [RXDart on GitHub.Com](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart)

Here you will find some very helpful **list of app state management approaches** that can lead you to a better way of app development:

- [App state management of Flutter.Dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)