# Class marked as @immutable, instance field not final using StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, final, instance-variables, statefulwidget

I have a Stateless widget called ToggleButtonsList and one of my instance fields, isSelectedType, is not set to final. This is the warning I am receiving because of this:

"This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: ToggleButtonsList.isSelectedType"

Here is a portion of my code:

```
class ToggleButtonsList extends StatefulWidget {
  ToggleButtonsList({this.type, this.stringList});

  final String type;
  final List<String> stringList;
  List<bool> isSelectedType = [];

  @override
  _ToggleButtonsListState createState() => _ToggleButtonsListState();
}

class _ToggleButtonsListState extends State<ToggleButtonsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   
  }
}
```

**My question:** I thought instance fields needed to be set to final **only for Stateless widgets, NOT Stateful Widgets**. Is this true? Is this a warning I should worry about since I'm not using a StatelessWidget or can I ignore it? My app seems to be working perfectly fine when I ignore the warning.

Reading the **"or a class that this class inherits from"** part of the warning made me try searching my project for any StatelessWidgets this class may inherit from and the only StatelessWidget I have in my project is from my main.dart :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      home: PriceScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Changing my MyApp class to a StatefulWidget didn't get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your mixing `State` and `StatefulWidget` class. The `Widget` class itself is `immutable` and both `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` extends from `Widget`class.

In your specific case, `isSelectedType` variable can be `final`, because final collections can grow or shrink. Only constant collections won't allow you to grow or shrink.

What you need to do:

```
class ToggleButtonsList extends StatefulWidget {
  ToggleButtonsList({this.type, this.stringList});

  final String type;
  final List<String> stringList;

  @override
  _ToggleButtonsListState createState() => _ToggleButtonsListState();
}

class _ToggleButtonsListState extends State<ToggleButtonsList> {
  List<bool> isSelectedType = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that although you can make the list final and thus appease the compiler, it is still a wrong thing to do (for reasons described in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Both stateful and stateless widgets need to be immutable.
This is enforced by `@immutable` on `Widget` class.

See [Flutter: Mutable fields in stateless widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192469/flutter-mutable-fields-in-stateless-widgets):

> Stateless widgets should only have final fields, with **no exceptions**. Reason: When the parent widget is rebuilt for some reason (screen rotation, animations, scrolling...), the `build` method of the parent is called, which causes all widgets to be reconstructed.
>
> Classes the extend `StatefulWidget` must follow the same rule, because those are also reconstructed. Only the State, which can contain mutable fields, is kept during the lifetime of widget in the layout tree.